# How write mysql query corresponding this tables

Tags: mysql

This is my database tables
[image]

I want to get this result:

[image]

How can I write select query to get that result?

Comment: You can do something like that with joins and subquerys(for the count and sum parts)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use dynamic SQL ([`PREPARE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/prepare.html), [`EXECUTE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execute.html)) for that

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
  'SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(o.date, ''%Y%m'') = ', 
  DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m'), 
  ' THEN op.count ELSE 0 END) `', DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m/%Y'), '_Count`,',
  'SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(o.date, ''%Y%m'') = ', 
  DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m'), 
  ' THEN op.count * op.price ELSE 0 END) `', DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m/%Y'), '_Sum`'))
  INTO @sql
  FROM `order`;

SET @sql = CONCAT(
  'SELECT c.name,p.title,', @sql,
  '  FROM `order` o JOIN order_product op 
       ON o.id = op.order_id JOIN client c
       ON o.client_id = c.id JOIN product p
       ON op.product_id = p.id
    GROUP BY o.client_id, c.name, op.product_id, p.title');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d3cb/7)** demo

---

To simplify things on the calling end you can wrap it up into a stored procedure like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_monthly_report()
BEGIN
  SET @sql = NULL;

  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
    'SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(o.date, ''%Y%m'') = ', 
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m'), 
    ' THEN op.count ELSE 0 END) `', DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m/%Y'), '_Count`,',
    'SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(o.date, ''%Y%m'') = ', 
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m'), 
    ' THEN op.count * op.price ELSE 0 END) `', DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m/%Y'), '_Sum`'))
    INTO @sql
    FROM `order`;

  SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT c.name,p.title,', @sql,
    '  FROM `order` o JOIN order_product op 
         ON o.id = op.order_id JOIN client c
         ON o.client_id = c.id JOIN product p
         ON op.product_id = p.id
      GROUP BY o.client_id, c.name, op.product_id, p.title');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Sample usage:

```
CALL sp_monthly_report();
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68ce6/1)** demo